# Addon for metro version of IE10

Tags: microsoft-metro, browser-addons, internet-explorer-10

I need to create simple addon, that may read current site's page and modify it (like Chrome's javascript extensions). Also it would be great if it can add its menu item to browser's context menu, or add its icon to some place in browser (like in Chrome near the omnibox).

I am developing the program for Windows 8, that must interact with site's forms (read them and modify).

Comment: I suggest you want to write the Addon for the metro IE (cause of your `metro-ui` tag)? If you want to do this, you should know, that this is not possible. Only the desktop version of IE10 will support Addons.

Comment: @JanK. I have mentioned "Metro version of IE10" in question title. I have read that it's plugin free. And what about extensions? Not plugins :)

Comment: @SteelRat Metro got rid of plugins for security and performance; I'm pretty sure that means no extensions either.